# Workaround to Android SurfaceView touch lag

Tags: android, surfaceview, touch-event

I've finished programming a functional Android game, but I don't know where to look to fix touch lag: Anytime the screen is touched, the framerate drops in half. My code is basically a copy and paste of LunarLander with an onTouchEvent.

Google searches show me basic workarounds they say work but don't (sleeping onTouchEvent, onDispatchEvent, onInterceptTouchEvent, synchronized, etc.) and it seems like it's impossible to use SurfaceView without immense lag during touch events.

What should I do? Should I abandon SurfaceView, disable onTouchEvent and use a clickListener, somehow block the rapid touch calls? Please, tell me what's wrong!

I've tried:

- Making onTouchEvent() run no code and return false
- Sleeping the onTouchEvent() or run() for 16/32/1000 milliseconds, no difference
- Overriding onDispatchevent() instead of onTouchEvent()
- Experimenting with synchronized() in onTouchEvent()

And here is my code:

```
public class Surface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    public CanvasThread canvasThread;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;    

    public Surface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            return canvasThread.touch(event);
        }

        class CanvasThread extends Thread {

    @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (this) {
                    // game logic
                }   
            }

            public boolean touch(MotionEvent event) {
                // touch logic
            }
        }
}
```